# Refresh VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How can I refresh a visualforce page after the save button on the page is clicked? I've tried a few methods, and none have provided the behavior I am looking for.

1. `window.location.reload()`
2. `window.location.reload(true)`
3. Returning the page's url from a function.

   ```
   public pagerefrence methodname(){
       PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/VFPage');
       pr.setRedirect(true);
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you add Save button code also

Comment: I think you are partially refreshing the page with the help of rerender attribute.

Comment: Without making an [edit] to your question, and including the save button and possibly some of the visualforce page, it will be difficult to provide a quality answer to this question. You may have `rerender`'s specified, or other code which is preventing a rerender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I need to rerender a page, I use a function which returns a `null` `PageReference`.

```
public PageReference RerenderPage() {
    return null;
}
```

This will rerender any sections specified in a `reRender` attribute on your button, and if none are specified, it will rerender the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your page by two ways.

1. In `yourmethod` put pagereference code and give the same link.

   ```
   public pagerefrence methodname(){
        return new PageReference('/apex/VFPage');
   }
   ```
2. Put oncomplete in your commandlink and reload the page using javascript:

   ```
   oncomplete="window.location.reload();"
   ```